# Why is bash 'not always' showing the 'Terminated' message after killing a process?

Tags: linux, bash, background-process

Why does this difference matter? The two blocks in the code below differ by the last line:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
    sleep 1 &
    p=$!
    kill $p &> /dev/null
else
    sleep 1 &
    p=$!
    kill $p &> /dev/null
    /bin/true # This line is the sole difference.
fi
```

Name it `a.sh`, and I get (on my Linux box)

```
$ ./a.sh
/a.sh: line 16: 18103 Terminated              sleep 1
$ ./a.sh foo
$ # no "Terminated" message
```

Why no message in the second case? Bash's basic behavior is to print "Terminated" ([see this queostion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65902)).

(NB I use `p=$!` in my true code, but in the above case you can use `kill $!`.)

EDIT: [Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/85039) kindly referred to the question "[Why are true and false so large?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/419697/190880)" in a comment. (It's rather a digression, but fun reading.) Unfortunately, the answer that comment belonged to was deleted, so I here record it. Thanks Sergiy.

Comment: Huh, interesting. It also doesn't print anything in either case if you replace `/bin/true` with just `true` (tested with `kill $!` rather than using a variable).

Comment: @Isaac: No. Read the mentioned question carefully. And its answers do _not_ answer my question. The answer to my question is: Because the shell **exits** (this point is lacking there, and answered for the first time in the [answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446269/190880) by [Sergiy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/85039/sergiy-kolodyazhnyy).) before checking the child process.

Comment: @Issac BTW your comment sheds some light on the community's readership: Three people upvoted your comment, rushing without understanding. ;-)

Comment: @teikakazura First: My name is Isaac, please. Second, the last line of [this answer say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65909/85039): *the previous explanation holds (the process is not dead yet).* So, there you have it: It is a problem of timing, nothing else. And third: Now it is five (not new) users that think your question is a duplicate. Whaich does not erase the question, just add a link to another answer.

Comment: @Isaac I'm sorry by calling you wrongly. **The rule** is to copy by dragging. (Never be lazy.) As for the third point, well, your comment is gone now...

Comment: For the duplicativity, no. In my question, the parent process is *not* interactive. The point you mentioned is essentially related to the prompt, and what's "not dead" is the child process. In my question, when the *parent process terminates* before checking the child process (that's Sergiy's answer), the message `<pid> Terminated` won't be shown. There's no necessity for such an implementation; it's the designers' choice. (Of course Sergiy got a hint from the mentioned answer to solve my question, which I myself failed to.)

Comment: Anyway I'm not reluctant to delete this comment as soon as it becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Matteo Italia's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65909/85039):

> Doing the same experiment with killall, instead, usually yields the "killed" message immediately, sign that the **time/context switches/whatever required to execute an external command cause a delay long enough for the process to be killed before the control returns to the shell.**

In other words, the delay caused by calling the external `/bin/true` cause a delay, which allows shell to print the message.

I've also performed tests with `/bin/echo` vs `echo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
    sleep 1 &
    p=$!
    kill $p &> /dev/null
    /bin/echo "a line"
else
    sleep 1 &
    p=$!
    kill $p &> /dev/null
fi
```

With this script:

```
$ bash ./mystery.sh 
$ bash ./mystery.sh foo
a line
./mystery.sh: line 11: 10361 Terminated              sleep 1
```

With built-in `echo`:

```
$ bash ./mystery.sh 
$ bash ./mystery.sh foo
a line
```

In other words, the fact that there is an external executable being called, forces the shell to perform check for child processes and background jobs when the last child returns. In case of:

```
if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
    sleep 1 &
    p=$!
    kill $p &> /dev/null
```

from your original script there's no extra command being called, only last built in.

---

Among other things, I've performed a few tests with `strace`:

It seems that the parent process exits and doesn't wait for the child. In other words, parent process of the shell exits too early to [perform an explicit check.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65909/85039)

```
$ strace -s 1024 -e kill bash mystery.sh 
kill(9830, SIGTERM)                     = 0
mystery.sh: line 11:  9830 Terminated              sleep 1
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=9830, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
$ strace -s 1024 -e kill bash mystery.sh  foo
kill(9839, SIGTERM)                     = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Notably, in tracing with positional parameter, the wait call is also absent:

```
$ strace -s 1024 -e kill,wait4 bash mystery.sh  foo
kill(9910, SIGTERM)                     = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
$ strace -s 1024 -e kill,wait4 bash mystery.sh
kill(9916, SIGTERM)                     = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=9916, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGTERM}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 9916
wait4(-1, 0x7ffe8e5bb110, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 9917
mystery.sh: line 11:  9916 Terminated              sleep 1
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9917, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, 0x7ffe8e5bb250, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
+++ exited with 0 +++
```